# Rcpp: speed up reading of an text file with big matrix (ESRI ASCii format)

Tags: c++, r, gis, rcpp

Usually I want to conduct a self defiened function on a batch of raster files (~365 layers, with ESRI ASCii format) for each grid, it will take a long time and large memory with raster package, so I am thinking about using Rcpp from reading each text files, and then do the caculation and export the final grid.

I have written a function for reading the text file, but it takes ~15 times more than the readGDAL and base reading function in the raster package, most times has been mainly spent in the split of ostream for each row and column, I am not familiar with C++, I wonder any one could help me to improve this script.

[The ESRI ASCii file looks like this](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/esri-ascii-raster-format.htm#), and the test code is listed below.

**test.asc**

```
"
ncols 480
nrows 450
xllcorner 378923
yllcorner 4072345
cellsize 30
nodata_value -32768
43 2 45 7 3 56 2 5 23 65 34 6 32 54 57 34 2 2 54 6 
35 45 65 34 2 6 78 4 2 6 89 3 2 7 45 23 5 8 4 1 62 ...
"
```

**test code:**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix cppread_asc(std::string path, const bool maskNA=true, const bool fast=true, const bool debug=false) {
  int ncols;
  int nrows;
  float cellsize;
  float xllcorner;
  float yllcorner;
  float nodata_value;
  std::string tmpstr;

  std::ifstream ascfile(path.c_str()); 
  if(ascfile.fail()){
    perror("Error, file does not exist");
  }else{
    // read the georeferencing data and metadata
    ascfile 
    >> tmpstr >> ncols
    >> tmpstr >> nrows
    >> tmpstr >> xllcorner 
    >> tmpstr >> yllcorner
    >> tmpstr >> cellsize 
    >> tmpstr >> nodata_value;

    Rcout<< "nrows:" << nrows << ", ncols;" << ncols << ";\n";
    NumericMatrix output(nrows,ncols);
    //Rcout<< "fast:" << fast <<"\n";
    if(fast){
      std::string tmpline;
      std::getline(ascfile,tmpline); //the first line is empty
      for(int row=0; row<nrows; ++row){
        if(debug && row<2){
          Rcout<< "start to getline\n";
        }
        std::getline(ascfile,tmpline);
        std::stringstream tmpss(tmpline);
        if(debug && row<2){
          Rcout << "tmpline:" << tmpline <<"\n";
          Rcout<< "start to seperate for column\n";
        }
        for(int col=0; col<ncols; ++col){
          tmpss >> output(row,col);
          if(debug && col<5 && row<5){
            Rcout<< "nrow of" << row <<", column of:" << col <<" value: " << output(row,col) << ";\n";
          }

          if(maskNA){
            if(debug && row<2 && col<2){
              Rcout<< "start to mask NA\n";
            }
            if(output(row,col)<=nodata_value){
              output(row,col)=NA_REAL;
            }                
          }
        }
      }
    }else{
      for(int row=0; row<nrows; ++row){
        for(int col=0; col<ncols; ++col){
          ascfile >> output(row,col); 
          if(maskNA){
            if(output(row,col)<=nodata_value){
              output(row,col)=NA_REAL;
            }                
          }
        }
      }      
    }
    ascfile.close();
    return(output);
  }
}


/*** R
require(raster)
require(microbenchmark)
r=raster(nrows=600, ncols=400, xmn=-10, xmx=10, ymn=-20, ymx=10, vals=0.001*1:(600*400))
writeRaster(r,filename= "test.asc", format = "ascii", overwrite=TRUE)
microbenchmark(
    new1<<-cppread_asc("test.asc",maskNA=TRUE,fast=TRUE,debug=TRUE),
    new2<<-cppread_asc("test.asc",maskNA=TRUE,fast=FALSE,debug=TRUE),
    new3<<-matrix(getValues(raster("test.asc")),nrow=600,ncol=400,byrow=TRUE),
    print(identical(new1,new2)),print(identical(new2,new3)),times=1
)
  */
```

```
#benchmark results:
#                     min          lq        mean      median          uq
#Rcpp_read  : 9127185.187 9127185.187 9127185.187 9127185.187 9127185.187
#Rcpp_read  : 9097437.947 9097437.947 9097437.947 9097437.947 9097437.947
#raster_read:  409822.642  409822.642  409822.642  409822.642  409822.642
```

Comment: Three things: 1. `notusecppsum()` looks a lot like `Rcpp::sum()`; please simplify your code. 2. you should iterate over columns first and then rows, because matrices are stored column-wise. 3. Please include the result of the benchmark, and make sure you're not comparing very small absolute times.

Comment: I haven't seen it benchmarked in a while, but the general rule also was that C-styile i/o was always (a lot?) faster than using `iostream` and friends.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks. Maybe I should try with fscanf.

Comment: @F.Privé, Thanks for your suggestion. I have fixed the code, and infact the sum function is not used.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, When I transform to using the C-style i/o, it speed up remarkly, this is the way I am looking up. However, I get an warning when using sprintf(fp, "%10.6f", &tmp), with unknown conversion type character '.' in format [-Wformat]. I wonder how can I preserve the digits number of float type when reading ? Now I get a value like 0.00100000004749745, which should be 0.001.

Answer (score 3):

The updated version with base C-style i/o is below, which run ten-times faster than the ostream manner, However, there is still two problems:

1: when I use the fscanf to get the dimension of nrows, ncols from the head lines, the integer value of nrows, ncols changed for several times, I do not why, I have to introduce two new keepnrows, keepncols to keep the value after fscanf immediately,I think this must be fixed, but I do not how to fix.

PS: Updated at April-6th, I have found what result in the error, it is because the tmpvalue is not initialized, see the code below. But I wonder WHY?

//float tmpvalue;

float tmpvalue=-9998.0;

NCOLS: 400

NROWS: 600

XLLCORNER: -10.000000

YLLCORNER: -20.000000

CELLSIZE: 0.050000

NODATA_value: -9999.000000

nrows:1635147585, ncols;1413563471;

NROWS: 1635147585

NCOLS: 1413563471

keepnrows: 600

keepncols: 400

2: about how to fix the ‘fscanf(fp,"%10.6f", &tmpvalue)’，with warning :unknown conversion type character '.' in format [-Wformat].
currently I get a float value like 0.001000000584, while it should be 0.001.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix cppread_asc(std::string path, const bool maskNA=true, const bool fast=true, const bool debug=false) {
  int ncols, keepncols;
  int nrows, keepnrows;
  float cellsize;
  float xllcorner;
  float yllcorner;
  float nodata_value;
//float tmpvalue; //This will result in serious erros that the ncols,nrows change always, I do not know why?
  float tmpvalue=-9998.0;
  std::string tmpstr;
  char tmpstring;
  
  if(fast){
    FILE *fp = fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      perror("error opening file");
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%s",&tmpstring);
    if(debug) printf("%s: ",&tmpstring);
    fscanf(fp,"%i",&ncols);
    keepncols=ncols;
    if(debug) printf("%i\n",ncols);
    
    fscanf(fp,"%s",&tmpstring);
    if(debug) printf("%s: ",&tmpstring);
    fscanf(fp,"%i",&nrows);
    keepnrows=nrows;
    if(debug) printf("%i\n",nrows);
    
    fscanf(fp,"%s",&tmpstring);
    if(debug) printf("%s: ",&tmpstring);
    fscanf(fp,"%f",&xllcorner);
    if(debug) printf("%f\n",xllcorner);
    
    fscanf(fp,"%s",&tmpstring);
    if(debug) printf("%s: ",&tmpstring);
    fscanf(fp,"%f",&yllcorner);
    if(debug) printf("%f\n",yllcorner);
    
    fscanf(fp,"%s",&tmpstring);
    if(debug) printf("%s: ",&tmpstring);
    fscanf(fp,"%f",&cellsize);
    if(debug) printf("%f\n",cellsize);
    
    fscanf(fp,"%s",&tmpstring);
    if(debug) printf("%s: ",&tmpstring);
    fscanf(fp,"%f",&nodata_value);
    if(debug) printf("%f\n",nodata_value);
    if(debug){
      Rcout<< "nrows:" << nrows << ", ncols;" << ncols << ";\n";
    }
    printf("NROWS: %i\n",nrows); printf("NCOLS: %i\n",ncols);
    printf("keepnrows: %i\n",keepnrows); printf("keepncols: %i\n",keepncols);
    nrows=keepnrows;
    ncols=keepncols;   
    NumericMatrix output(nrows,ncols);
    
    for(int row=0; row<nrows; ++row){
      for(int col=0; col<ncols; ++col){
        // fscanf(fp,"%0.20f", &tmpvalue);
        fscanf(fp,"%10f", &tmpvalue);
        output(row,col)=tmpvalue;
        if(debug && col<3 && row<3){
          Rcout<< "row: " << row <<", column: " << col <<" value: " << output(row,col) <<"tmpvalue: " <<tmpvalue<< ";\n";
        }
        if(maskNA){
          if(debug && row<2 && col<2){
            Rcout<< "start to mask NA\n";
          }
          if(output(row,col)<=nodata_value){
            output(row,col)=NA_REAL;
          }                
        }
      }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(output);
  }else{
    std::ifstream ascfile(path.c_str()); 
    if(ascfile.fail()){
      perror("Error, file does not exist");
    }else{
      // read the georeferencing data and metadata
      ascfile 
      >> tmpstr >> ncols
      >> tmpstr >> nrows
      >> tmpstr >> xllcorner 
      >> tmpstr >> yllcorner
      >> tmpstr >> cellsize 
      >> tmpstr >> nodata_value;
      
      // if(debug){
      //  Rcout<< "nrows:" << nrows << ", ncols;" << ncols << ";\n";
      //  }
      NumericMatrix output(nrows,ncols);
      for(int row=0; row<nrows; ++row){
        for(int col=0; col<ncols; ++col){
          ascfile >> output(row,col); 
          if(maskNA){
            if(output(row,col)<=nodata_value){
              output(row,col)=NA_REAL;
            }                
          }
        }
      } 
      ascfile.close();
      return(output);
    }
  }
}


/*** R
require(raster)
  require(microbenchmark)
  r=raster(nrows=600, ncols=400, xmn=-10, xmx=10, ymn=-20, ymx=10, vals=0.001*1:(600*400))
  writeRaster(r,filename= "test.asc", format = "ascii", overwrite=TRUE)
  microbenchmark(
    new1<<-cppread_asc("test.asc",maskNA=TRUE,fast=TRUE,debug=TRUE),
          new2<<-cppread_asc("test.asc",maskNA=TRUE,fast=FALSE,debug=TRUE),
                new3<<-matrix(getValues(raster("test.asc")),nrow=600,ncol=400,byrow=TRUE),
                      print(identical(new1,new2)),print(identical(new2,new3)),times=1
  )
  */
```

```
#benchmark results:
#                     min          lq        mean      median          uq
#Rcpp_read  :  329938.034  329938.034  329938.034  329938.034  329938.034
#Rcpp_read  : 9097437.947 9097437.947 9097437.947 9097437.947 9097437.947
#raster_read:  409822.642  409822.642  409822.642  409822.642  409822.642
```